# No valid 'development' profiles were found

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-cordova

Im using Visual Studio 2013 with CTP 3.1. After I updated XCode to 7 I keep getting the error below when I try to build for release. Building for developement works. Why is it even asking for development profile when building for release?

MDAVSCLI : Code Sign error : No matching provisioning profiles found: No valid 'development' profiles were found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to figure out why this happens in XCode7 but I got around it by specifying the identity and provisiong profiles.

```
To force a specific signing identity
Create a res\native\ios\cordova folder in your Cordova project.
To override the signing identity or provisioning profile for the Debug configuration, place a custom build-debug.xcconfig file in this folder, or place a build-release.xcconfig file to override the Release configuration.
The base files can be found here on github.
build-release.xcconfig has a sample of the syntax for setting a signing identity.
When creating your own xcconfig file, be sure to include the following at the top of the file:#include "build.xcconfig"
For a complete set of build settings that can be overridden, see Xcode build settings.
```

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757048.aspx)